# Password length situation when trying to sign up on my website

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have made a code and when I try to sign up I get a problem saying the length is not between 5-30 for the password. I was using 7 letters for a password but was getting this problem when trying to sign up on my site. I have posted parts of the code below:

```
$reg = @$_POST['reg'];
//declaring variables to prevent errors
$fn = ""; //First Name
$ln = ""; //Last Name
$un = ""; //Username
$em = ""; //Email
$em2 = ""; //Email 2
$pswd = ""; //Password
$pswd2 = ""; //Password 2
$d = ""; //Sighn up date and time
$u_check = ""; // Check if username exists
//registration form
$fn = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
$ln = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']); 
$un = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']); 
$em = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']); 
$em2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']); 
$pswd = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']); 
$pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']); 
$d = date("Y-m-d"); //Year - Month - Day

if ($reg) {
if ($em==$em2) {
// Check if user already exists
$u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un' ");
// Count the amount of rows where username - $un
$check = mysql_num_rows($u_check);
if ($check == 0) {
// Check all of the fields have been filed in
if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2) {
// Check that passwords match
if ($pswd==$pswd2) {
// Check the maximum length of username/first name/last name does not exceed 25 characters
if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {
echo "The maximum limit for username/first name/last name is 25 characters!";
}
else
{
// Check the maximum length of password does not exceed 25 characters and is not less than 5 characters
if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)>5) {
echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
}
else
{
//encrypt password and password 2 using bcrypt before sending to database
$pswd = bcrypt($pswd);
$pswd2 = bcrypt($pswd2);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (' ', $un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
die("<h2>Welcome to YouBook</h2>Login to your account to get started . . .");
```

Comment: why are you using `@` before $_POST

Comment: @Arian To suppress errors/notices. This is a sloppy way of not using `isSet()`

Comment: please let me decide how long I want MY password to be. ditto for MY name

Comment: Any reasonable password hash shouldn't have a length restriction, implying that if your code requires the password to be between 5 and 30 characters that you're doing something wrong with how you're storing the password.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch bcrypt does :)

Comment: @PeeHaa true, but unless I'm mistaken it's 55 or 56 characters, so while I was completely wrong about the no limit part, it doesn't make sense to limit it to 30, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {
                           //      ^ You want to check if it is less than or equal to 5
```

p.s. You really shouldn't put a maximum limit on the password.

Comment: You'll need to remove that equals sign. Right now it is saying "if less than or equal to 5, reject registration" But you said 5 char is okay, so remove the =.

Comment: @GaryHayes - You're correct. I overlooked that. Thanks